# Why does Visual Studio rename my project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webmatrix, naming

A project I started in WebMatrix I go back-and-forth with - some things are easier to do in WebMatrix, but in general I'm more comfortable in VS, so... anyway, when I opened it in VS for the first time, I noticed that it had prepended "WebMatrix-" to the project name. Why? And will that be in any way a "gotcha"?

Comment: Was that default name of new project, or you cant get rid of that from name?

Comment: I named my project "GarrapataGallery" in WebMatrix. When I opened it in VS 2012, it was named "WebMatrix-GarrapataGallery"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will be a "gotcha" or not, but, honestly, probably not. In my experience, I have changed my whole site name, mid-project, and it remained error free to the end. It was then that I realized how little what WebMatrix calls your "site" name actually has to do with website functionality.

That having been said, I don't think you'll have any worries, since you can always just change your site name back, if need be.

There exists the option to open up Visual Studio from WebMatrix, but I have never tried it (if I need to make a class, I just make a .cs file and edit it using WebMatrix). A reference site is below, however, I am not sure how much info you'll find there to help you (I wasn't able to find a whole lot on this when I did a search, but maybe your own searches will yield better results to fit your scenario).

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/features.aspx

For now, all I can say is that you're probably not gonna run into any true "gotcha"s. You can always rename the site for WebMatrix right before the completion of your project, if need be.

Answer (score 2):

First, WebMatrix will prepend WebMatrix- to the solution name not the project name.
Second, this will only happen if you open the site by clicking on the visual studio button in WebMatrix.

There is no gotcha. And you can rename this solution to any other valid solution name.